# javascript popup blocker and ajax callback - C# MVC app

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

There are 2 requirements in a secure website in which a form is being posted to an url:

1. The form will be posted to a *new* window if authentication ticket is still valid, otherwise the *same* window will redirect user to the login page.
2. Posting the form to new window will *not* invoke popup blocker.

I have gone as far as writing an ajax action to get correct answer on whether auth is still valid or not. **But I'm unable to get the redirect code to come outside the script execution context and thus avoid popup blocker**. Please help!

JavaScript:

```
    $('#someSystem').click(function () {
        //deferred promise?
        auth().done(function (result) {
            //need to move below code outside this callback without side effects
            if (result == 'true') {
                var form = $('#ssoForm');
                form.submit();
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "/account/login";
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    function auth() {
        return $.ajax({ url: '/account/isauthenticated', method: "POST" });
    }
```

HTML for already authenticated user

```
<form action="/sso/somesystem" id="ssoForm" method="post" target="_blank">
    ...
    <div id="someSystem">Continue</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you will be able to do anything short of adjusting the pop-up block to avoid it. If the js could do that it would almost completely defeat the purpose of the blocker. Also you should think about the security of doing your redirect in js because the code is in user space.  The user could cancel the redirect from their browser.

Instead why not do the check on the server and use

```
 RedirectToAction()
```

Comment: It will be a task to educated users to add the site to popup blocker exceptions. `RedirectToAction()` will redirect within same window.

Answer (score 0):

After reading several jQuery posts and even signalR, [this codeproject.com article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net) was the most helpful for my case. It seems there is a simpler way to handle this. Developer does not know whether the authentication is valid or not at a given time, but definitely knows *after how long* it will expire. This knowledge can be hard coded in a JavaScript and an alert can be sent to the user preemptively (`setTimeout`), instead of waiting for them to click and *then* try to figure out. This approach will not let me disturb the popup blocker.